# iOS autolayout animation

Tags: ios, animation, autolayout

For example, when I click on the button when the following code execution:

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] init];
[self.view addSubview:view];
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[view mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
    make.leading.equalTo(@0);
    make.trailing.equalTo(@0);
    make.bottom.equalTo(@-100);
    make.height.equalTo(@320);
}];


[view mas_updateConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
    make.bottom.equalTo(@-200);
}];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f animations:^{
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}];
```

But the animation is very strange, not what I want. If you add a constraint not immediately executed animation, such as this:

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] init];
[self.view addSubview:view];
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[view mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
    make.leading.equalTo(@0);
    make.trailing.equalTo(@0);
    make.bottom.equalTo(@-100);
    make.height.equalTo(@320);
}];


dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(1 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [view mas_updateConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.bottom.equalTo(@-200);
    }];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f animations:^{
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];

});
```

This time animation to normal. Oops, almost forgot to say, autolayout I use the [Masonry](https://github.com/Masonry/Masonry)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you also need to call `[self.view setNeedsLayout]` in order to discard current view layout before calling `[self.view layoutIfNeeded]`.

Comment: iOS7 needs, iOS8 is not required